# In SSIS SQL command What the ? means in set variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-query-store

In SSIS package SQL command

```
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(32)
SET @UserName = ?

DECLARE @SecurityGroupID INT
SET @SecurityGroupID = ?
```

what does the ? means

Comment: Theyre positional parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? means parameter. In your case @UserName = @param1 and @SecurityGroupID = @param2.

You have to map the value of each parameter